# Syntax Errors in my Python code but I don't see where?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap

The error is in the last line of code with the error saying `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```
# Step 10 - DISSOLVE RDiffIntersect using FID_RDiffBuffer and FID_"AreaFileName"

arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features="RDiff_AreaIntersect",
out_feature_class="C:/Users/User/Desktop/claudio.gdb/RDiff_AreaIntersect_Dissolve",
dissolve_field="FID_RDiffBuffer",
ORIG_FID, statistics_fields="OBJECTID_1 FIRST;FID_RDiffBuffer FIRST;gps_latitu FIRST;gps_longit FIRST",
ORIG_FID FIRST, multi_part="MULTI_PART", unsplit_lines="DISSOLVE_LINES")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have positional arguments following key word arguments:

`ORIG_FID`, and `ORIG_FID`

You also have a white space between `ORIG_FID` and `FIRST`

The following doesn't throw a `SyntaxError` but may be inexact:

```
arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features="RDiff_AreaIntersect",
                          out_feature_class="C:/Users/User/Desktop/claudio.gdb/RDiff_AreaIntersect_Dissolve",
                          dissolve_field="FID_RDiffBuffer",
                          ORIG_FID = 0,  # change this value to the one you need
                          statistics_fields="OBJECTID_1 FIRST;FID_RDiffBuffer FIRST;gps_latitu FIRST;gps_longit FIRST",
                          ORIG_FID=0,  # change this value to the one you need
                          FIRST = 0,  # change this value to the one you need
                          multi_part="MULTI_PART",
                          unsplit_lines="DISSOLVE_LINES")
```